# Rails: Strong Params Not Working, Forbidden Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I'm replacing some `params.permit!` methods which are a violation of the Brakeman gem.

Here's a method I insert into the traditional update method. The method looks like this.

This works!

```
  def update_all_burdens
    params.permit!
    @time_period_hour.update(params[:time_period_hour])
    @time_period_cost.update(params[:time_period_cost])
    @burden_response.update(params[:burden_response])
    @burden_hour.update(params[:burden_hour])
    @burden_cost.update(params[:burden_cost])
  end
```

This does not work, it gives forbidden attributes error. However i'd like to permit these params safely.

```
  def update_all_burdens
    params.permit(:time_period_hour, :time_period_cost, :burden_response, :burden_hour, :burden_cost)
    @time_period_hour.update(params[:time_period_hour])
    @time_period_cost.update(params[:time_period_cost])
    @burden_response.update(params[:burden_response])
    @burden_hour.update(params[:burden_hour])
    @burden_cost.update(params[:burden_cost])
  end
```

If permitting those params one by one isn't working, how is another way to figure out what the params I need to permit are?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`params.permit!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21) changes the internal state of `params`, while [`params.permit(attr, ...)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) returns a new `ActionController::Parameters` instance that includes only the given filters and sets the permitted attribute for the object to true. So you should be doing something like this:

```
permitted = params.permit(:time_period_hour, :time_period_cost, :burden_response, :burden_hour, :burden_cost)
@time_period_hour.update(permitted[:time_period_hour])
@time_period_cost.update(permitted[:time_period_cost])
@burden_response.update(permitted[:burden_response])
@burden_hour.update(permitted[:burden_hour])
@burden_cost.update(permitted[:burden_cost])
```